# Erlang utf-8 hex to decimal

Tags: utf-8, erlang, hex

I'm trying to convert the hex `0x80 0x94` (utf-8) into the corresponding decimal value `2014`

Is it possible to do that conversion in Erlang?

Comment: Do you mean you want a unicode codepoint for some utf-8 encoded binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't convert it is simply that it's not valid `UTF-8`.

```
4> io:format("~.2B~n", [16#80]).
10000000
ok
5> io:format("~.2B~n", [16#94]).
10010100
ok
```

See the Description on [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for details (I am showing you the binary so you can see the binary pattern). But it comes down to `80h` being an invalid starting value in `UTF-8`.

I think what you might want a unicode codepoint from a `UTF-8` binary like so:

```
unicode:characters_to_list(<<"I am a valid utf8 binary">>, utf8).
```

By the way codepoint `2014` is [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07de/index.htm) character which is `0xDF 0x9E` in `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the binary `utf8` conversion for that.  Though it looks like your numbers are off:

```
2> A = <<16#80, 16#94>>.
<<128,148>>
3> <<B/utf8>> = A.
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<128,148>>
```

The transformation works both ways, so this is what I'd expect to start with:

```
5> <<2014/utf8>>.
<<223,158>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little confuse with the question. (Sorry about that)...

In erlang Hex numbers are prefixed using 16# so If you have number 16#80 or 16#94 and you want to convert it to decimal value you can use integer_to_list(16#AF8, 10)

Comment: Sorry about the bad question formulation, it was late. Well, I am aware of the base 16 conversions. But the problem is this is not 16 bit. So fx. when I do integer_to_list(16#8094, 10). it returns 32916. While the value I'm looking for is 2014.

Comment: How do you get 2014?? Decimal value for the given hex should be 128 and 148.  Try K = "\x80\x94".